# Moto (mock_s3) not mocking boto3 in flask requests

Tags: python, flask, pytest, boto3, moto

Currently, this is the test I have written:

```py
from moto import mock_s3
import boto3
import pytest

s3_url = "/doc"


@pytest.fixture
def generate_doc(test_client, jwt_token):
    def _generate_doc(jwt_token):
        return test_client.get(
            s3_url,
            headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {jwt_token}"},
        )

    return _generate_doc

@mock_s3
def test_generate_doc(generate_doc):
    client = boto3.client("s3")
    client.create_bucket(Bucket="bucket_name", CreateBucketConfiguration={'LocationConstraint': 'us-west-2'})
    response = generate_doc(jwt_token)
    assert response.status_code == 200
```

The function that uses boto3 uses it in the `/doc` URL.

It does not mock the boto3 calls, I changed my profile settings to be sure tests only passed using the mock.

I've tried using the mock_s3 at different points in the module, how can I resolve this?